# Godaddy : linking domain name to IP address

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, subdomain

I just bought a domain name for my web site from GoDaddy.

the content of the site is available at a public IP address.

how do I link my domain name to the IP address ?

how do I make it so that when someone types in my domain name, the content of the web server is displayed ?

thanks.

Answer (score 11):

You will want to add an A-record for your root domain (mydomain.com)

And if you want to get fancy, also add a CNAME (www.mydomain.com) subdomain

There are two steps, and GoDaddy has hard-to-find articles. Reposting text here:

**ADD AN A RECORD**

An A (host) record connects your domain name to your IP address. A records let users enter your domain name in a Web browser to access your website. They are the most common type of zone record.

Follow the directions to access the DNS Manager.

Click Add Record.

From the Record type list, select A (Host).

Complete the following fields:
Host Name — Enter the host name the A record links to. Type @ to point the record directly to your domain name, including the www.

Points to IP Address — Enter the IP address your domain name uses for this host record.

TTL — Select how long the server should cache the information.
Click OK, then click Save Zone File. The new A record displays in the A (Host) section.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236

**ADD A CNAME RECORD**

A CNAME (Alias) record points to an A (Host) record. You can create multiple CNAME records and point them to an A record. The most common CNAME records are the subdomains www and ftp.

CNAME records make your DNS data easier to manage. If you change the IP address of an A record, all CNAME records pointed to that A record automatically follow the new IP address. The alternative solution, multiple A records, is not as simple as using CNAME records.

Follow the directions to access the DNS Manager.

Click Add Record.

From the Record type list, select CNAME (Alias).

Complete the following fields:
Enter an Alias Name — Enter the subdomain name for the alias assignment. For example, type www.
Points to Host Name — Enter the host name you want the alias to point to. For example, type @ to map the alias directly to your domain name.

TTL — Select how long the server should cache the information.

Click OK, then click Save Zone File.

You can click Restore Defaults in the CNAME (Alias) section of the Zone File Editor to restore the default CNAME records for your domain name.

https://www.godaddy.com/help/add-a-cname-record-19236

Hope this helps, if you still haven't figured it out since 2010!

Answer (score 1):

Does this: http://help.godaddy.com/article/666 help?

Comment: thanks. just did it. but it doesn't yet display the content of my website. is there any period of time to wait for before it starts working ?

Comment: DNS can take up to 24 hours to propagate through the internet.

Comment: Yes, but in practice normally this is 2-3 hours.

Comment: it's been 2 hours I did the config and right now, any attempt to access the page yields : 

"Failed to Connect. Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at pdftomp3.com."

Comment: @Lokpere: `dig` and `nslookup` both resolve your domain name. `ping` and `mtr` either never succeed or give an error. A browser gives a host not available error.

Comment: Agh @thijs this link doesn't exist anymore! Wondering if I could find an archive somewhere..